# Exp-resso Store how to set language

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to set the default language to Dutch on the front-end of Store?
I can't see it in the CP.

Right now I'm getting partial translated Errors when leaving required fields blank. Like: "The Naam field is required" Where "Naam" is the dutch translation.

Is Store looking on OS or browser lang settings?

I hope I can set it so it's always Dutch.

Tnx,
Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to download the Dutch language pack for both Store & EE. Then in the Super Admin account you will want to set Dutch as the language that EE uses and make sure that members prefs control the site. From there Store should use Dutch in the CP and for error messages.

Another thing to mention that if you are using inline_error handling you can create custom error messages in your template instead of using the default store messages.

For example lets say you have a form that has

```
{field:billing_name} {error:billing_name}
```

This would show the default Store error message if the user did not fill it out. If you change it to something along the lines of

```
{field:billing_name} 
{if error:billing_name}
Whoa buddy! We can't sell you something without knowing your name.
{/if}
```

You can change the message that is shown to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I think the EE language pack is missing. `The x field is required` comes from the EE language pack, but the `Name` field comes from the Store language pack, hence why you're seeing a partial translation.

Comment: Ah, all makes sense. I'v got the EE lang pack installed but maybe missed some settings.

Answer (score 0):

Exp-resso store uses the same default language Expression Engine does.

Check: https://github.com/expressodev/store-language for available languages.